# PHP Warning: json_encode(): Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument with GBP (£) pound symbol

Tags: php, json, utf-8, php-5.4

Can anyone advise why I get the following error:

`PHP Warning:  json_encode(): Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument`

When `json_encode`'ing the following array (output to the Apache error log):

```
Array\n(\n [currency] => GBP\n [currency_symbol] => \xa3\n)\n,
```

With the following code (I am using PHP 5.4.45):

`echo json_encode($output);`

I am making the request with AJAX, and when I look in the console I see this:

> "currency":"GBP","currency_symbol":null

...so it looks like when it errors PHP simply returns it as `null`

Is there any reason why this would happen only with the `£` symbol and not USD (`$`) or EUR (`€`)?

Answer (score -1):

Try to write

```
 mysqli_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8')
```

**before** your SELECT query.

The most common problem is the retrieving of the data that's not exactly the same charset than the expected result.

### EDIT

IT's safely if you use the proper PHP function to this:

```
 mysqli_set_charset('utf8');
```

See more: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php

Comment: Where did you read this came from a database? Besides that you're using a deprecated function.

Comment: @Daan, they aren't deprecated, he said `mysqli_` but accidentally linked to `mysql_`

Comment: That's a reason to downvote? @Daan you are wrong... this problem came in 99% of the cases by a incongruence in the charset of the database and the charset of the code

Comment: Ok, there are some trolls, as usual... :)

Comment: Sorry for `mysql_*` functions, I was edited and @Prisoner helps to fix the link. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

try with `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` before that set `default_charset` to `UTF-8`:

```
<?php
    ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');
    $email_hooks = array(
            "forgot_password" => array(
                    "name" => "Forgot Password",
                    "keys" => array(
                            "site_url" => "Site URL",
                            "current_date" => "Curremt Date",
                            "user_name" => "User name",
                            "name" => "Name of the user",
                            "reset_url" => "Url for resetting password",
                            "user_email"  => "£"
                    )
            )
    );
     echo json_encode($email_hooks,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

**OUTPUT:**

> {"forgot_password":{"name":"Forgot Password","keys":{"site_url":"Site URL","current_date":"Curremt Date","user_name":"User name","name":"Name of the user","reset_url":"Url for resetting password","user_email":"£"}}}

Comment: I think the same. Why the downvotes? There are trolls. When someone make a downvote, he must to explain why, but here nobody explains nothing. I like your solution. Maybe both of them are correct. We need to wait to OP's judgement. Good luck!

Comment: @Suchit Thanks for taking the time to reply to my question. I'm sorry to see that someone is trolling you by downvoting with no explanation. It's the most annoying thing about SO, sadly.

Comment: @crmpicco can you tell us what solution works for you? Are you retrieving from database?

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Yes, I am retrieving the data from a MySQL database table which has a `CHARSET=utf8`. Using `ini_set` just before doing a `json_encode` seems a touch hacky, why do I only need to do this for a `£` symbol?

Comment: Did you see my answer ? It has 2 downvotes, but we have troll visits to this post... Please, see my answer and try it. In the most cases that happens your error, it can be fixed with the  `set charset` SQL sentence (or `mysqli_set_charset()` function)